# Runing coroutines in IntelliJ Kotlinx error

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-coroutines, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to run a native Kotlin project using coroutines using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2020.

Here is how my build.gradle looks:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.72'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    // For ARM, should be changed to iosArm32 or iosArm64
    // For Linux, should be changed to e.g. linuxX64
    // For MacOS, should be changed to e.g. macosX64
    // For Windows, should be changed to e.g. mingwX64
    mingwX64("mingw") {
        binaries {
            executable {
                // Change to specify fully qualified name of your application's entry point:
               entryPoint = 'sample.main'
                // Specify command-line arguments, if necessary:
                runTask?.args('')
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        // Note: To enable common source sets please comment out 'kotlin.import.noCommonSourceSets' property
        // in gradle.properties file and re-import your project in IDE.
        mingwMain {
        }
        mingwTest {
        }
    }

}

// Use the following Gradle tasks to run your application:
// :runReleaseExecutableMingw - without debug symbols
// :runDebugExecutableMingw - with debug symbols
```

And here is a simple KT file:

```
package sample

import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {

    val deferred = async(Dispatchers.Unconfined, CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        println("Running Async Unconfined: on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name} has run.")
        42
    }

    val result = deferred.await()
    println("Async Unconfined Result is ${result}")

}
```

I installed the maven plugin under Project Structure | Module and screenshot attached.

[image]

Nevertheless, I'm getting "Unresolved References..." error. Attached screenshot...

[image]

Request if someone can help me to resolve this please?

Thanks

Comment: Seems there is no coroutine package under kotlinx !!

Comment: Could someone please help me here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies` tab, you selected `Runtime` as the scope, which makes the dependency only available at runtime (usually used for transitive dependencies). Try selecting `Compile` here.